# How do I handle this NULL data?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CATEGORIE](
    [bijdrage_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [categorie_id] [int] NULL,
    [naam] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,)
```

I use this query to retrieve the data:

```
select c.bijdrage_id, c.categorie_id AS Subcategorievan, c.Naam from CATEGORIE as c
```

With the following c# code I put all my values into Categorie objects:

```
public List<Categorie> geefAlleCategorien()
        {
            List<Categorie> categorien = new List<Categorie>();
            string query = "select c.bijdrage_id, c.categorie_id as SubCategorieVan, c.Naam from CATEGORIE as c";
            SqlDataReader reader = db.Select(query);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Categorie c = new Categorie();
                c.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                c.SubCategorieVan = reader.GetString(1);
                c.Naam = reader.GetString(2);
                categorien.Add(c);
            }
            db.Close();
            return categorien;
        }
```

My problem is that some of the values in the "categorie_id" column are NULL and the "reader.GetString(1)" method can't handle NULL values.

How can handle these NULL values with my c# code?

Comment: use `ISNULL()` in your sql code. `isnull(c.categorie_id,'')` will replace it with a blank space. Or... make it NOT NULL in your table definition ;)

Comment: `categorie_id` is an `int`, not a `string`

Comment: Only return the rows from the database where catagory_id is not null.

Comment: You could force a "null value", for example since `categorie_id` is an int, just relate @scsimon's comment to check:: `isnull(c.categorie_id, -1)` or something along those lines.

Comment: I went with the ISNULL() method in the query in the end. This gave me the cleanest solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`IsDBNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Categorie c = new Categorie();
c.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
c.SubCategorieVan = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : reader.GetString(1);
c.Naam = reader.GetString(2);
categorien.Add(c);
```

Comment: It's real unnecessary performing this check in application code when this can be done @ DB tier in your query and probably the cleanest solution than this

Comment: @Rahul: what means _unnecessary_? There is no overhead in doing this in the application layer and it was explicitly requested by OP: _"How can i handle these `NULL` values with my **c# code**"_

Comment: Well it's unnecessary not because there is no overhead but rather no point in doing this. about OP ... see his last comment *I went with the ISNULL() method in the query in the end. This gave me the cleanest solution*

Comment: @Rahul: it depends on where you want to handle these NULL values. Maybe the value that will be displayed instead will be provided in the application layer or even in the gui. It totally depends on the requirement and the architecture. If a question states that this should be done with C# code, i'll try to provide a solution that does exactly this. OP is free to change his requirements of course.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use `COALESCE()` function in your SQL and return a default value like

```
select c.bijdrage_id, 
coalesce(c.categorie_id,0) AS Subcategorievan, 
c.Naam 
from CATEGORIE as c
```

Comment: _"How can handle these NULL values with my c# code?"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Yeah right but it's unnecessary handling it in application code. Rather it's  a DB operation and should be offloaded to DB

Comment: Why? There's no overhead in doing  this in the application layer: _"How can i handle these `NULL` values with my **c# code**"_

Comment: I agree with Tim. What would be the default value for a string? An empty string? And an `int?` Sometimes the code simply NEEDS a null from the database.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, a `null` in the database does not return a C# `null`, but a `DbNull.Value`. If a c# `null` was returned, the problem would be solved for all reference types (but not all value type). So when a column inside a database is nullable, you have to check for a `DbNull.Value`.

You have serveral options:

- Test using `SqlDataReader.IsDbNull(...)`.
- Test using the `as` operator in combination with `SqlDataReader.GetValue(...)`. This works only with nullable types.

Examples:

```
c.SubCategorieVan = reader.IsDbNull(1) ? null : reader.GetString(1);
```

or

```
c.SubCategorieVan = reader.GetValue(1) as string;
```

Or... if you want to give your properties a default value, when a DbNull is returned, you can give a default value in your code:

```
c.SubCategorieVan = reader.IsDbNull(1) ? "Leeg" : reader.GetString(1);
```

or

```
c.SubCategorieVan = reader.GetValue(1) as string ?? "Leeg";
```

You could create an extension method:

```
static public T GetValue<T>(this IDataReader reader, int columnIndex, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    return reader.IsDbNull(columnIndex) ? defaultValue : (T)reader.GetValue(columnIndex)
}
```

This way, your reading method could become nice and clean:

```
c.Id = reader.GetValue<int>(0);
c.SubCategorieVan = reader.GetValue<string>(1, "Leeg"); // In case you want to use this default value.
c.Naam = reader.GetValue<string>(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is better with extension methods....
Here is a little gem I've found a long time ago somewhere on the internet:

```
public static class IDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this IDataReader reader, int index)
    {
        return (Convert.IsDBNull(reader[index])) ? default(T) : (T)reader.GetValue(index);
    }

    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this IDataReader reader, string name)
    {
        return reader.GetValueOrDefault<T>(reader.GetOrdinal(name));
    }
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
c.SubCategorieVan = reader.GetValueOrDefault<int>(1);
```